# Only some props are being loaded into state

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to initialise some inputs with data from props. This data will then change so need to set my initial state to the value of props. I know that generally this would be considered an anti-pattern, but as I'm only seeding this data it shouldn't be an issue.

I initially call my component and pass it it's props like this.

```
 render(){
    return (

    this.state.BrakeVals.map((id, index)=> (

        <FormUpdateLine key={index}
        BrakeID={this.state.BrakeRef[index]}
        FuelID={this.state.FuelRef[index]}
        LocationID={this.state.LocationRef[index]}
        SpeedID={this.state.SpeedRef[index]}
        SteeringID={this.state.SteeringRef[index]}
        BrakeVal={this.state.BrakeVals[index]}
        FuelVal={this.state.FuelVals[index]}
        Latitude={this.state.LocationLats[index]}
        Longitude={this.state.LocationLongs[index]}
        SpeedVal={this.state.SpeedVals[index]}
        SteeringVal={this.state.SteeringVals[index]}
        />
        ))
);
```

And then inside of this component I'm trying to set the initial state like this.

```
import React from 'react';
import firebase from './Firestore.js';
class FormUpdateLine extends React.Component{
   constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state = {
       BrakeVal: this.props.BrakeVal,
       FuelVal: this.props.FrakeVal,
       Latitude: this.props.Latitude,
       Longitude: this.props.Longitude,
       SpeedVal: this.props.SpeedVal,
       SteeringVal: this.props.SteeringVal,
   };
 }
```

What this causes is this

```
Key"0"
Props
BrakeID:
"Jw9pn4pspnOsxigjkLNk"
FuelID:
"Wd3FMoGsf78F6UVDDoDa"
LocationID:
"DGOKkb105gGIKVs62WvI"
SpeedID:
"4ls9yGm2MZLB8pitQomV"
SteeringID:
"OlAF9e44IjmzbynlsaYm"
brakeVal:
"1"
fuelVal:
"1"
latitude:
"1"
longitude:
"1"
speedVal:
"1"
steeringVal:
"1"

State
BrakeVal:
"1"
```

What I find most interesting about this problem is that if add in BrakeID into my state, it also manages to load that into the state.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Directly loading into state will show unpredictable behavior.
Load everything into state at the [componentDidMount()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) and it'll be available on the first visible render cycle.

Comment: I added the following function and the behaviour is still the same 
   `componentDidMount()
    {
        this.setState({
        BrakeVal: this.props.brakeVal,
        BrakeID: this.props.BrakeID,
        FuelVal: this.props.fuelVal,
        Latitude: this.props.latitude,
        Longitude: this.props.longitude,
        SpeedVal: this.props.speedVal,
        SteeringVal: this.props.steeringVal
    })
}`